# Running Plotly charts in Slidify or R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I am trying to build R Markdown presentation document using plotly charts , but its not showing us charts in the browser . Code below :
[image]

````
========================================================

```{r,echo=false}
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = clarity)) +
            geom_bar(position = "dodge")
ggplotly(p)
```
````

Comment: if I remove echo=false, it works for me

Comment: Interesting ! I removed echo=false , then Code appears in markdown presentation , but still <!html_preserve> coming instead of plot . Thanks , for working on it though,

Comment: fyi, I am using plotly_3.4.3  ggplot2_2.1.0

Comment: Okay I am using same version for ggplot2 but my plotly version remains at 3.4.1 even after I installed it again from CRAN ? anything I am missing here ?

Comment: it's the development version I have. library(devtools); devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")